# Trust Querying Event in Ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm implementing a payment solution in Ethereum Blockchain. And an important security question is making me doubt.

First I create an address where the customer need to send the ERC20 token. In my back-end I call Infura as a node providers to check the that transfer event has been emitted.
So far, all is good, right ?

It's probably stupid but my question is : how can I trust that the event is valid ? I mean, how can I be sure that the blockchain which the node has is the right one and that the event will not be cancelled if another chain replace the one my node has ?

Thank you in advance for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, you need to trust Infura (or generally any 3rd party node provider that you might be using) that they're feeding you the correct data. I'm sure they have several very highly skilled teams working on the product, and processes to deal with all kinds of scenarios. But inherently you need to trust them, yes.

If you [run your own node](https://ethereum.org/en/run-a-node/), then you can rely on your local copy of the blockchain. And theoretically, you can go through all the hundreds of thousands of lines of code of your node client software (e.g. [Go Ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/) is opensourced) to ensure that your node is really validating the received data according to the EVM specification in the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), and that it's forwarding the correct data to your backend app.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. Even if I run my own node, when can I pretend that the transaction and smart contract execution is definitive ? For example in bitcoin we said that we need in practice to wait for 6 blocks to consider as defintive. 
Is there something similar with Ethereum ? I wouldn't like to catch the event log too quickly whereas transaction is not complete

Comment: @Remi_la Validators on PoS networks can vote on rejecting the latest epoch (on Ethereum, 1 epoch is 32 blocks). After an epoch is accepted, it becomes "**justified**", and one epoch later it becomes "**finalized**" ... Even though the rejection is very uncommon, the completely safe approach is to wait until the epoch, in which your block was produced, is **finalized**. So on Ethereum that's up to 2 epochs, or 64 blocks (~13 seconds per block * 64 = ~14 minutes). You can find more detailed info and links at https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pos/#finality

Comment: So if I understand well. Metamask for example, show new balance just once the transaction has been added to a block. And the block is neither justified nor finalized ? 
How often it occurs that the transaction is reverted ?