# How to get a block's statut for a transaction in Ethereum network

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js

This question follows a previous one that I asked : [Trust Querying Event in Ethereum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156698/trust-querying-event-in-ethereum).

In my back-end I listen for an event after a specific transaction. My back-end get the event just after the transaction is added to a new block. However to be sure that the block will not be removed we need to wait that its statut becomes 'finalized'.

My question is : how can I manage to do it using ethersjs ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am just poking around stackoverflow for the first time and noticed your question. Since you're building automation around event monitoring, I wanted to recommend a great, free tool that handles this issue around block finality before exposing the event data you need via REST API.

https://www.hal.xyz/products/hal-stream

Hopefully it is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find an ideal solution. However I tried something like this and it seems to work :

```
            provider.on(filter,async (log) => {
            const listener ={
                async action(){
                    try{
                        let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi)
                        let amount = iface.parseLog(log).args.tokens;
                        let blockHash = log.blockHash;
                        let transactionHash = log.transactionHash;
                        let removed = log.removed;
                        if(!removed){
                            this.executedPayment = await ExecutedPayment.create(
                                {
                                    PaymentId:uuid,
                                    Amount:ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount, DECIMAL_USDT),
                                    TransactionHash:transactionHash,
                                    BlockHash:blockHash,
                                    StateId:1
                                }
                            )
                            clearTimeout(this.finalizationTimeout);
                            this.finalizationTimeout = setTimeout(async () => {
                                await this.executedPayment.update({StateId:2})
                                await this.executedPayment.save()
                                provider.off(filter)
                            }, 900000) //if no reorgs happened in the last 15 minutes, we consider the block as finalized
                        }else{
                            this.executedPayment.update({StateId:3})
                            clearTimeout(this.finalizationTimeout);
                        }
                    }catch(e){
                        console.log("An error occured : "+e)
                    }
                }
            }
            listener.action()
        })
```

If you have another solution I'll be glad to know.